# typescript path alias needs module-alias/register on every file

Tags: javascript, typescript, module-alias

I am using typescript `v3.6.4` with the following `tsconfig.json` snippet:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@config": ["config"],
    }
  }
```

and module alias in package.json:

```
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@config": "dist/config"
  }
```

I have the following folder structure:

```
src
 |-config
     |-index.ts
 |-app
     |index.ts
     |logic.ts
 |-dist
```

Now in app/index.ts, if I do:

```
import 'module-alias/register';
import config from '@config';
```

and my `npm start` commands is:

```
"start": "node -r ts-node/register ./src/app/index.ts",
```

`tsc` will compile successfully but `npm start` will give error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@config' in src/app/logic.ts
```

And the only way to fix this is to also add

```
import 'module-alias/register';
```

in `src/app/logic.ts`

Seems I have to add the `import 'module-alias/register'` in every file that I do alias? Is it a way to configure this?

Comment: Does the error only occur if you build and run the app?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht the build works fine, it only happens on run time.

Comment: That's what I meant. You have to import the `module-alias/register` only once in you `app/index.ts` it should load all other imports in e.g. in `app/logic.ts` without the need to import it there again. That's also what their docs say.

Comment: That's needed because the typescript compiler does not update the paths in the generated files (with what you specified in the `tsconfig.ts`). That's why you need to load `module-alias/register` and of course in order to make it work you have to at least import in once, otherwise the packages code would not be included.

Comment: If that solved it for you I will right an answer, so please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you use the `paths` instead?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht yes that's what I did - I already imported it in app/index.ts, which gives me the runtime error and to fix that error I have to import it again in app/logics.ts which is against their docs, that's why I asked this question ;)

Comment: @Kousha can you be more specific? I already have `paths` in the tsconfig file

Comment: Have you tried the `require('module-alias/register)` syntax?

Comment: did someone resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

### *@2021*

For me I've got exact the same issue: typescript allowed me only use the module aliasing when the every module has `import 'module-alias/register';` at its top line when it has such module alias.

After spent nearly whole day, I got the point:

***`tsc` won't help to transpiling these decorators. so you have to make sure every *consumer* of the js compiled code have acknoledged and know how to deal with these module imports with alias.***

i.e.:

```
node index.js
=>
node -r module-alias/register index.js

///

mocha .
=>
mocha -r module-alias/register .
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is quite simple:

in the root file, like app/index.ts, put the `import 'module-alias/register';` to the end of all the other imports and you won't need to put it in every file. It didn't work for me because I put that import before all other imports, not after.

For example:

```
import express from 'express';
import corsFilter from 'cors';
...
import 'module-alias/register'; // This has to be after all other imports
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what is recommended on their README fyi